# Using "rather" to correct a misstatement

Tags: word-usage

For some reason I have it in my head that I can use the word "rather" at the end of a phrase to indicate that I am correcting a previous misstatement.

For example:

> Down the hall, you'll find the bathrooms on your left...right, rather.

Is this in typical usage anywhere, or am I just crazy?

Comment: Are those questions mutually exclusive? ;-)  I've heard that usage of rather and it's not extremely common but not unheard of.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I'm crazy, at least it's not without company.

Comment: It's more common than you suggest on this side of the Atlantic, Kristina. _Rather_ in this incarnation is a pragmatic marker subclass correction marker. The Australians use 'correction' before the corrected version. The nearest definition I can find is this from the AHD: 3. More exactly; more accurately: _He's my friend, or rather he was my friend._ However, this is showing improved precision rather than outright correction of an error. (The AHD also sadly has rather in the dustbin adverb class.) _Rather_ has quite a few senses - none adverbial in my estimation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Guess that counts for an answer. This is one of those few good Qs. in the *usage* tag.

Comment: You could sub-classify that as *conversational*, *teen-lingo*, or such I suppose.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- What POS is it in:  "His model airplane flew rather well."?

Comment: The analysis I buy into groups modifiers of adjectives and of adverbs as 'secondary modifiers', though it would probably be better to divide them into two obvious classes. Some are intensifiers (very, extremely, highly); some are qualifiers (barely, a little (a multi-word example) ). Some vary with context - _rather_ can mean _fairly_ or _very_ in your example, and the intonation would indicate which if spoken. Many secondary modifiers have more semantic content - eg _dazzlingly_ bright; terminally ill; brutally honest

Comment: @me: The usage of _rather_ in sentences such as 'I rather thought that might happen' parallels  that of say _wholeheartedly_ in _He believes wholeheartedly in the benefits of exercise._ This is an obvious use of _rather_ as an adverb. I stand corrected.

Comment: Now if just some of you would bake this into an answer, I'd happily upvote and be able to accept and close the question :) Or I suppose I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's fairly acceptable usage.

As with so many words in the language, rather can be used to mean several different things.

- somewhat/moderately,
  e.g. "In height he was rather over six feet, and so excessively lean that he seemed to be considerably taller" - A Study in Scarlet
- considerably/considerably (yup, kindof the opposite of the previous meaning),
  e.g. "“I ﬂatter myself that I have managed it rather neatly,” the detective answered proudly" - A Study in Scarlet
- preferably/instead,
  e.g. "If my view of the case is correct, and I have every reason to believe that it is, this man would rather risk anything than lose the ring." - A Study in Scarlet
  e.g. "Having ﬁnished his scrutiny, he proceeded slowly down the path, or rather down the fringe of grass which ﬂanked the path, keeping his eyes riveted upon the ground." - A Study in Scarlet
  e.g. "‘Arthur would rather that we spoke the truth,’ the girl answered ﬁrmly." - A Study in Scarlet

It's in the third sense that your sentence employs rather. I've used several examples for this particular meaning to demonstrate usage.

Of course, the way you use it is more common in speech than in writing. What you are doing is squeezing out the "or" from the sentence and flipping the sequence.

> That is why I have chosen my own particular profession,—or rather created it, for I am
>   the only one in the world. - The Sign of the Four

Comment: Not entirely sure the examples in your third sense are all the same, but +1 anyway for finding so many examples from one book.